# How to share object in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a constant array:

```
export const gender = [{id: 1, name: "Male"}, {id: 2, name: "Female"}];
```

How to share this `gender` array across components? To fill select list in template?

Comment: put it in a file, add a import reference to that file

Comment: @j4rey That just makes for unmaintainable code. To make modifications to the array you would then be doing it within the component. So now everywhere you reference the array you have to maintain it in multiple files. Using a service you only have to maintain it in one file.

Comment: its not a mutable data, creating a service is an overkill. Keeping it in a file like **constants.ts**. Any component or service that needs it can simply access it with `import {GENDER} from './constants'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case maybe a typescript constant is sufficient.

Other possibilities:

**environment.ts**: But since you have ids in your constant they may vary in different environments. So you could put the constant also into `environments/environment.ts`. See: https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-environment-specific-defaults

**Dependency Injection**: If you need more flexibility you could also inject them with a  `InjectionToken`. See:  https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

```ts
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export const GENDERS = new InjectionToken<Gender[]>('genders');

@NgModule({
 ...
  providers: [{
    provide: GENDERS, useValue: [{id: 1, name: "Male"}, {id: 2, name: "Female"}];
  }]
})

class Component {
  constructor(@Inject(GENDERS) public genders: Gender[]) {...}
}
```

With dependency inject you could also use a factory to configure your array at runtime or use another array for a part of your application by defining a custom providers in a component:

```ts
@Component({
providers: { provide: GENDERS, useValue: [{id: 3, name: "Rainbow"}] }
})
class MyComponent....
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) and put the array in the service as a property. Then, using the constructor of the component, load the service in each component you want to use the `gender` property.

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyService {
  public readonly gender = [{id: 1, name: "Male"}, {id: 2, name: "Female"}];

  public addGender(gender: any) {
    this.gender.push(gender)
  }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-1',
  template: '<button (click)="onAddOtherGender()">Add other gender</button>'
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit {
  public constructor(private readonly myService: MyService){}
  public ngOnInit() { console.log(this.myService.gender) }

  public onAddOtherGender() {
    const id = this.myService.gender.length
    this.myService.addGender({id, name: "Other"})
  }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-2',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of myService.gender">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
  public constructor(public readonly myService: MyService){}
  public ngOnInit() { console.log(this.myService.gender) }
}
```

Comment: Overkill no need for that since we know gender can be limited whats the point to make it like this to add different genders? we can simple define const with all three possible genders and can use anywhere by importing const?

Comment: if you're sharing a value with a service, you really should be using rxjs. This set up can cause SO many weird and hard to detect bugs.

Comment: @KamranKhatti The question is about sharing data between components, this demonstrates that. Just because gender doesn't change doesn't mean this does apply to other items.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn sharing data with components doesnt always mean to have a service there are other possible ways as well like a shared constant, enum etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since we know that genders can be limited and not something which frequently changed, the simplest and best way which suits current scenario could be adding genders in a common const files where we define all constants of the app.

**constants.ts**

```
export const gender = [{id: 1, name: "Male"}, {id: 2, name: "Female"}];
```

Now import gender and use it anywhere

```
import { gender } form './constants';

gender = gender

console.log(this.gender)
```

Or use in template

```
<div *ngFor="let g of gender"> {{ g.id }} - {{ g.name }} </div>
```